# How do I hide button and drop down arrow from Vue bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to hide the drop down arrow and button color, I'm using `vue-bootstrap`. is there any other method that I can use to make a drop down in my `navbar` without arrow and button color? I already tried a lot of method but it seems like every styling that I do is not working on `vue-bootstrap`

```
<b-dropdown
id="dropdown-left"
text="RECIPE"
ref="dropdown"
class="m-md-2">
   <b-dropdown-item>A</b-dropdown-item>
   <b-dropdown-item>B</b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

And There is source of package:[dropdown-bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown)

Comment: can you make jsfiddle or codesandbox of what you've used so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gotta override the style of the default classes responsible for what you see in the dropdown component, I don't know whether you want to change the dropdown permanently in the app or is it in just one case so either you give your dropdown a class name & use this styles or simply override the default classes in your stylesheet like this:

```
.btn-secondary { /* this is the button's class */
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}
.dropdown-toggle::after{ /*this is responsible for the arrow you see in the button*/
    display:none;
    }
    

.btn-secondary.focus, .btn-secondary:focus, .btn-secondary:hover { /* this will change the button's hover & focus effect*/
    color: #000;
    background-color: #e7e7e7; /*just assumed you want it to be colored on hover IDK */
}
.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .show>.btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle { /*and apparently this is responsible for when the button is active*/
     color: #000; 
    background-color: #e7e7e7; 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use [`no-caret`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown#hidden-caret) prop to hide the arrow/caret:

```html
 <b-dropdown no-caret>
   <!-- your content here -->
 </b-dropdown>
```

---

Use `toggle-class` to style your dropdown button toggle:

```html
 <b-dropdown variant="link" toggle-class="my-custom-toggle" no-caret>
   <!-- your content here -->
 </b-dropdown>
```

```css
.my-custom-toggle {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**toggle-class** prop could be an `Array`, `Object` or `String`. Similar to `:class` bind in vue.js

---

Check all `<b-dropdown />` properties here --> https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown#comp-ref-b-dropdown-props